# Designing classes to cope with frequent database schema changes

Tags: c#, class-design

I am working on a database that is maintained by another system, so I am unable to make any drastic changes to the tables. The tables in this database have quite a few fields (upwards of 30+) with no two tables having the same naming convention, types, or same number of fields. These tables also change fairly frequently (fields being added, removed or their types being changed) and to make matters worse new tables are created on a frequent basis as well. Now I do have one table that can be strictly typed which is used as a queue.

**The problem:**

I have to get data from a table given the table name and some columns in that table. The column names are supplied as strings. Since these tables change so often it becomes difficult to maintain strictly typed entities for each table.

How would I design my classes in a way that they are loosely coupled but allow me to work with these tables?

Thanks for the help and sorry if my explanation sucks.

Comment: What do you need to do with the data once you get it from the DB? If you don't need to do anything which requires it to be typed, then you can treat contents of every column as a string.

Comment: So to be clear:  your database schema changes more regularly than your code is deployed?  If so, that is an...unfortunate situation.

Comment: It's an MSSQL server. Basically I will have templates that will give the column names for various tables that would like to be used (if a table changes, we just update the template). Using these templates I create a document that has the values of the columns. Similar to crystal reports I guess.

Comment: What type of application is this? winform, web, service?

Comment: Are you doing anything with the data other than creating a document?

Comment: It's a service. No the data is just retrieved and added to a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use [SQL Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/ms162169.aspx) with [Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.aspx) to dynamically create strong types.

```
Server srv = new Server(conn);
Database db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks"];

foreach (Table table in db.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" " + table.Name);
    foreach (Column col in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + col.Name + " " + col.DataType.Name);
    }
}
```

I've written unit test generators for Data Access Layers this way and you could make up Classes using the column DataTypes, eg (look online for a better implementation - in C#):

```
Public Function SQLParameterType(ByVal ParameterDataType As String) As String

    ParameterDataType = ParameterDataType.ToUpper

    If ParameterDataType.IndexOf("NVARCHAR") > 0 Then
        Return "string"
    ElseIf ParameterDataType.IndexOf("VARCHAR") > 0 Then
        Return "string"
    End If

    Select Case ParameterDataType

        Case Is = "BIGINT"
            Return "Int64"
        Case Is = "INT"
            Return "Int32"
        Case Is = "SMALLINT"
            Return "Int16"

        Case Is = "BIT"
            If gIsVBdotNet Then
                Return "boolean"
            Else
                Return "bool"
            End If

        Case Is = "DATETIME"
            Return "DateTime"

        Case Is = "DATETIME2"
            Return "DateTime"

        Case Is = "SMALLDATETIME"
            Return "DateTime"

        Case Is = "MONEY"
            Return "single" 'float
        Case Is = "FLOAT"
            Return "single" 'float
        Case Is = "REAL"
            Return "double"
            'Case Is = "INT"
            '    Return "int32"
            'Case Is = "INT"
            '    Return "int32"
        Case Else
            Return "666"
    End Select

End Function
```

With this simple ORM that connects to your database in a schema-neutral way you can loosely couple dynamically generated classes to the dB. The new [Dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) type in .Net 4 seems to be a good polymorphic datatype candidate for this application.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. Although not the implementation that I used, you did lead me in the right direction especially with the Dynamic type. When I get a working example I will post my solution for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what sort of business logic you can derive from unstable data.  My assumption is that you are doing some work on the meta data associated with the records.  Working with the aggregates of the data (counts, averages, etc) rather then actual data.

I would use a DataSet, use a generic SQL statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM {dynamic table name}
```

Comment: I am working with the actual data. A DataSet would work in this case, but I am just not sure how to separate working with the data and working with the database in this case. I would like to work in some dependency injection for testing, I guess this is the part that ultimately confuses me.

Comment: Before I go further ... are there joins involved?

Comment: What type of operations on the data are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

An quick fix (not a solution) would be to use a code generation utility [like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27830/SQL-Class-Shell-Generator) one which would update/create your class files based on your templates or the datatabse schema definitions themselves. With a little bit of work this could be fully automated in your project via [custom MsBuild task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx) which would run when you build your project & your files would be updated directly into you solution folder.

But most importantly it would break your code upon build when your tables definitions get updated - showing you where you have to fix things due to table definition changes. For this to work your custom MsBuild task must run before the main build task as [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This would definitely benefit you and make things easy for you because I've seen such design benefit a similar project but in the end the 'crap in - crap out' principle would still prevail so the above 'fix' would only treat the symptom not the cause which is likely a poor design and lack abstraction and analysis of what your solution data needs are. Hence you get a program which needs to be re-programmed in order to be re-configured:) but for LOB programming, it's not unusual:)

** Note: If you decide to use the design described in the first paragraph, in order to have a complete solution you may need to have an additional MsBuild task which would automatically checkout the files which need to be updated from you source control when the schema changes. Comment bellow if you need more info on this.

**To summarize**: what will happen is when your press F5 to build your solution in Visual Studio all your classes will get magically updated with the latest definitions from the database. You can also constrain this to happen on `Release` builds only so that you don't get this done every time you build in `Debug` mode while you are developing.

Comment: Similar idea to my answer. The problem with a code generation utility is that you have to compile the code and in this question the OP's database changes more than the code. Hence unless Minky distributes the CSCompiler he/she will probably need to take my advice and bake in all the functionality to dynamically generate classes on-the-fly.

Comment: Compilation of the code is optional via MsBuild which would in turn call csc.exe (it's not very easy to call csc.exe manually). Also I suspect only .NET developers will be developing his application so MsBuild & the csc compiler will be present.